# Setting a Class Object as a property of another Class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, strong-references

I'm pretty new to Objective C so maybe this is really simple, but I built a class which will store among other things a class reference. This is what I have in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class *filterClass;
```

Where I'm getting suck is that I am not able to assign class objects to an instance of this class they way I can add them to arrays or variables:

```
Filter *filter1 = [[Filter alloc] init];
filter1.title = @"Sepia";
filter1.filterClass = [GPUImageSepiaFilter class];
```

I am getting an error:

> "implicit Conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__unsafe_unretained
>   Class *' is disallowed with ARC"

It seems like it wants the filterClass property to be strong but that also gives and error, because as I understand it you can't define primitive types as strong. Obviously I could just store strings as references to the classes and use -NSClassFromString, however it would be nice if I could just pass the class objects around. Since I can put them in arrays and it seems like it should be possible. Let me know if I'm going about this completely wrong.

Comment: `Class` is a type that can hold a pointer to a class object. Like other pointers to objects, it can be strong or weak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property declaration must be

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class filterClass;
```

instead of

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class *filterClass;
```

Please check this answer [Objective-c - Class Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009278/objective-c-class-keyword)